# Python telegram bot - reply when user says specific words

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Context: I am starting to learn how to code a telegram bot in python. I have successfully made a fun bot for my group with friends to use. However, i only want it to respond when specific words are mentioned apart from the commands that trigger it.
Example: Whenever a user says the word "wen" plus any other word(s), i want the bot to reply with: SOON!
I want the bot to only pick up some trigger words and reply and for the remainder of the chat to stay idle

Part of my code:

```
       user_message = str(input_text).lower()
       wenResponse = str("wen ").join(input_text)
      
       if user_message + wenResponse:
           return ("SOON!")
   
   def handle_message(update,context):
       text=str(update.message.text).lower()
       response=sample_responses(text)
       update.message.reply_text(response)
```

Actual result:
The bot is working but only when the user says specifically "wen". If the user adds more words after "wen" the bot doesnt pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if "wen" in str(input_text).lower():
    return "soon"
```

This should work even if the key word isn’t the first word.

Comment: You need to call `.lower()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `.startswith('text')` to check is a string starts with `'text'`.

The `.startswith('text')` return `True` if the string starts with `text`, or else it will retur `False`.

Comment: Thank you very much fren! Worked like a charm! Much appreciated, no voting power but as soon as i can ill up :)